# Googlemaps elevation API giving an error when passing arguments

Tags: python, google-maps, google-api, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to get the elevation from an excel file using pandas to read the file and jupyter notebook.  I'm currently trying to figure out why my code is producing an error.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
import os

import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key= "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
elevation = gmaps.elevation("40.88292", "-98.37342")
print(elevation)
```

Its returning the error:

```
  File "C:/Users/gabe/Desktop/a.py", line 6, in <module>
    elevation = gmaps.elevation("40.88292", "-98.37342")
  File "C:\Users\gabe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\googlemaps\client.py", line 409, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: elevation() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I have tried using a ton of different variations of the coordinates as arguments but it always returns this error.

Comment: Try `gmaps.elevation([("40.88292", "-98.37342")])` ? https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/index.html#googlemaps.Client.elevation

Comment: Its giving another error` TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'`

Comment: I'll go check something. As an aside, the sourceforge page for the module says _* Note: The Google Maps V2 API used by this module has been deprecated. *
For V3, consider pygeocoder: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygeocoder_, although I don't know if that message is up to date.

Comment: How about `gmaps.elevation(("40.88292", "-98.37342"))` ?

Comment: Returns the same error :(

Comment: That’s bizarre...

Answer (score 1):

Docs say to pass in a list of locations, which can be a list/tuple of latlon coordinates.

So likely:

```
gmaps.elevation([("40.88292", "-98.37342")])
```

should work (as per @AMC comments)

you could alternatively build the json request yourself following the [API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/start)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
latlon = ["40.88292", "-98.37342"]
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
url = f'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations={",".join(latlon)}&key={api_key}'
response = urlopen(url)
result = json.load(response)
```

result

```
{'results': [{'elevation': 568.84423828125,
   'location': {'lat': 40.88292, 'lng': -98.37342},
   'resolution': 4.771975994110107}],
 'status': 'OK'}
```

Comment: Hello you! The list of coordinate tuples was my first suggestion too (check the comments on the main post), but OP said they tried it and got another error.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.  I ended up using a different module and got it to do what I wanted.  I should have just built the json request from the getgo.

Comment: @AMC you changed your name! glad to see you're still going strong on here.. I remember when you had like 400 reputation XD...added a note in my answer, I actuallly was referencing your comment but should have mentioned it